# Excel VBA crashing while altering code

Tags: excel, crash

I ran into a frustrating problem here. Im using Excel 2013 on Win 10 x64. I have a module with several Subs and Functions. Now, when I want to alter a Function from

Function SomeName(someVar as String) As **String**

to

Function SomeName(someVar as String) As **Boolean**

then Excel will become non-responsive in the moment I finish editing. I have to kill it using the Taskmanager. Just to be clear, Im not running any of that code, it happens during the editing process.

Has anyone a hint for me? whats going on here?

Many thanks